# Launching xunit tests from ReSharper under Moles

Tags: c#, resharper, xunit, moles, pex-and-moles

I have got xunit tests working great; launching them from ReSharper. Now I'm trying to use moles for some test cases. I've got my `[Moles]` attribute on the test, with a reference to the moles xunit extension, and yet it's complaining that "Moles requires tests to be IN an instrumented process." I assume this means I need to run it through moles.runner.exe or something. Is there a way to set this up to run using ReSharper to launch it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this is an unresolved bug in ReSharper: please vote for [this bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-260304) to have it fixed earlier rather than later :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use NUnit right now but on my tests I use:

```
[HostType("Moles")]
public void method()...
```

Try that and see if it resolves.